# Which second separator to use in URL?

Tags: seo, url, clean-urls, delimiter

I'm already using `-` as a separator in my URLs, for some reasons I need to add a second one.

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) I can use `.`, `_` and `~`. I also have seen some sites using `+` as a separator. I'm wondering which one to use, I read many articles about pro/cons for each separator and I can't decide.

- `/salty-recipes`
- `/salty+spicy-recipes`
- `/salty_spicy-recipes`
- `/salty~spicy-recipes`

Comment: What is wrong with `/salty-spicy-recipes`?  I don't see any need for multiple separators here.

Comment: Maybe if we knew the "some reasons" why you think you need a "second separator"  it would help answer your question? Maybe a different approach altogether is required? Maybe another path segment? The three suggestions above just look odd.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller @DocRoot I need it for searching, the example above is a bit simplified. In this URL `/term1_term2-term3_term4` I'm aiming to search `term1` and `term2` in category 1, and  `term3` and `term4` in category 2. I can use URL parameters, but I need a clean url, I'm also aware of duplicate content.

Comment: When you use underscores, Google will think the terms are related.

Comment: You could also consider a slash (`/`) or a period (`.`) as a separator there.

Comment: @closetnoc I think google treats underscore as a separator, in the past it was not the case. @StephenOstermiller I may can consider `.` (although it can be interpreted as a file extension), `/` is also a valid separator, but the URLs will not be restful

Comment: Google does treat peking_duck as related terms (as in a phrase, proper name, etc.) and peking-duck as separate terms even if they are found in an ontology. This is an old semantics analysis standard that Google found to remain true in search. Each term (peking and duck) should perform just as well for individual searches of each term, however, where someone searches "peking duck" peking_duck should perform better. And while peking duck is an obvious phrase and likely to be in an ontology, eco friendly manufacturing may not be. This is why the signal exists.

Comment: @closetnoc that make sense, thanks! In my search context, the terms are not related (they are tags for each category), this will limit the second separator to `+`, `.` and `~`

Comment: In your case, choosing `+`, `.`, and `~` should not matter much. Each should work the same as `-`. However, do know that `~` has historically represented a user directory such as example.edu/~john/. I would personally skip this one just in case.

Comment: Be aware that some browsers (and servers) will decide to treat a `+` as a space ` `, which might therefore end up as `%20` when it reaches your code.

Comment: On top of that, REST is perfectly happy with query strings for things like search terms, especially when combining multiple categories. You mentioned duplicate content, which will happen if you can put the category terms in any order. Query strings also make it easier to understand which category the terms relate too.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, If I needed to use an operator other than a hyphen '-' I would use an underscore because it seems cleaner and is often used for variables when writing code.

In your comments you said you're needing the extra operator to perform a search using the words in the URL. If this is the case I would probably use the plus '+' symbol. Many websites replace spaces with the plus symbol and so if you're aiming to parse the URL into separate words this may be easier.

The only other option I would suggest is using URL parameters like `url.com?var1=term1&var2=term2` and using a .htaccess file to convert it to a clean, readable URL like `url.com/term1/term2/`.

The link below is a great article about using .htaccess files. The first point explains what I mentioned above.

https://moz.com/blog/htaccess-file-snippets-for-seos

Answer (score -3):

I guess this is the best that love the google!

```
/salty-recipes
```

I'm always using this separator for my projects.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.